# Looking up Personal / Documents folder is not showing the right location

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vsto, known-folders

My background is more Web Development so this might be an easy question. I have an MS Word Add-In which was originally built to use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`

It has been reported that we should be using the CSIDL_PERSONAL variable which maps to the registry key for Personal Shell Folder. From what I can tell, the SpecialFolder is the standard way of accessing this but it still seems to resolve to the User's Documents folder even if I change the registry key to a different location such as a network drive.

Does anyone know a better way to use the CSIDL_PERSONAL path or why I am having troubles with the SpecialFolder?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but the wiki tag for `known-folders` here on SO says that it is the replacement for CSIDL. I don't know if it's accurate, but it seems likely, so the idea that you should use a CSIDL instead is suspect.